# Best practice to handle unsupported preview image sizes

Tags: android, android-camera, preview

my application uses image processing on camera preview images. Unfortunately it requires a certain preview image size (1280x720) which is not supported by all devices out there. I am currently working on making it more flexible (more preview screen sizes) but up to now I need to find a solution to filter all devices which do not support this size.

As far as I have understood the Google docs regarding filters in the Play Store (http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) I cannot filter for preview sizes (only for screen resolutions).

Of course I can read out the supported preview image sizes with `getSupportedPreviewSizes()`, but only if the App is already installed. Closing the App afterwards with a "not supported" hint would be very rude.

Does anyone have an idea about what could be done in this case? Is there a best practice method for that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your app could generate them itself. Further you could explain on `camera preview image`. What is that exactly? Where do they reside?

Comment: The camera preview image is used to create a preview for the user. (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#camera-preview). It is used to run image processing algorithms as every image can be accessed in the `public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] coloredData, Camera camera)` method of the `SurfaceHolder.Callback`. Or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Sorry I still do not know where these preview images reside. Are they separate files somewhere in the filesystem? Or are they contained in .jpg's taken by a camera app? Apparently they are not generated on the fly.